# Key press anywhere on the form

Tags: c#, winforms, keydown

How can I determine what key user pressed, no matter where is the focus (as long as they are using the application)?

For example, they press "<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>" (quit) and the program exits no matter what.

Normally i'd have to go to the form event of KeyDown, and make that condition there. But what if the form wasn't focused? Then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> wouldn't work.

How can I do this in windows forms applications? I'm sure it's simple but can't find a way.

Comment: What do you mean by "what if the form wasn't focused"? Do you have multiple forms, or do you mean another application might be focused? Do you just need to set KeyPreview to true on the form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is commonly referred to as a *system-wide hotkey*.

Windows Forms does not inherently support system-wide hotkeys which means  you will either need to manually register and manage each system-wide hotkey by means of the native [`RegisterHotkey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646309(v=vs.85).aspx) function or use a third-party library such as [Shortcut](https://github.com/ByteBlast/Shortcut).

Should you choose to manually register and manage each system-wide hotkey,  [here is an article](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207) and [here is a screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvtV3jc4maY&list=UUORNOWODd_t4qYgzsb64EVg) that should help you.

*(Full disclosure: Shortcut is a project of mine, as is the screencast).*

Comment: Yes! [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvtV3jc4maY) video you gave me has actually more information that I needed, that's exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Your question is unclear - but given this quote:

> How can I determine what key user pressed, no matter where is the focus (**as long as they are using the application**)?

I'm going to assume you are not looking for a system-global hotkey, just an application-global hotkey.

If you have only one form, you just need to set the [KeyPreview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property of your form to true.

This has the effect of sending all keypress events (KeyDown etc) to the form first, even if a control on the form has the focus.

Then you can simply implement your KeyDown handler as you mention in the question.

If you have multiple forms, then you might need to do this on each one.